# Rotate labels on tiles generated by Maperitive

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, openlayers

I'm using custom generated tiles on web map (displayed using openlayers).
Tiles are generated by maperetive and it's great. However my map is rotated -3/4Pi (openlayers has this feature) and many labels are rendered upside down. 
I belive maperitive has no feature to render labels relative to arbitrary angle. May be there are other options to fix this?

[image: Example of rotated label]

Comment: Try re-asking this question at http://gis.stackexchange.com or http://help.openstreetmap.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem altering dll's of Maperitive (v2.4.1) using [dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy).

Placement of labels is done by `Karta.MapLabeling.Igor2LineFeatureLabelPlacementAlgorithm.EvaluatePosition()` method (from Karta.dll). Below is the altered method. I added `+ 225f` in three places. 225(deg) is equvalent of -3/4*Pi(radians). The added value should be positive.

```cs
public static LabelPositionEvaluation EvaluatePosition(IPolylineAnalysis polylineAnalysis, float position, float? lengthAround)
        {
            if (lengthAround != null)
            {
                float? num = lengthAround;
                if (num.GetValueOrDefault() <= 0f && num != null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lengthAround");
                }
            }
            LabelPositionEvaluation labelPositionEvaluation = new LabelPositionEvaluation(position);
            float polylineLength = polylineAnalysis.PolylineLength;
            float num2 = (lengthAround != null) ? (position * polylineLength - lengthAround.Value) : 0f;
            float num3 = (lengthAround != null) ? (position * polylineLength + lengthAround.Value) : (polylineLength * 0.9999f);
            labelPositionEvaluation.Fits = (num2 >= 0f && num3 <= polylineLength);
            if (!labelPositionEvaluation.Fits)
            {
                return labelPositionEvaluation;
            }
            IPolylineWalker polylineWalker = polylineAnalysis.CreateWalker();
            polylineWalker.MoveTo(num2);
            int currentSegment = polylineWalker.CurrentSegment;
            float num4 = (polylineAnalysis.SegmentLengths[polylineWalker.CurrentSegment] - polylineWalker.CurrentOffsetWithinSegment) * polylineWalker.CurrentAngle;
            polylineWalker.MoveTo(num3);
            int currentSegment2 = polylineWalker.CurrentSegment;
            if (currentSegment2 == currentSegment)
            {
                num4 = ((lengthAround != null) ? (polylineWalker.CurrentAngle * lengthAround.Value * 2f) : (polylineWalker.CurrentAngle * polylineLength));
            }
            else
            {
                num4 += polylineWalker.CurrentOffsetWithinSegment * polylineWalker.CurrentAngle;
            }
            float num5 = 0f;
            for (int i = currentSegment; i < currentSegment2; i++)
            {
                float num6 = (float)GeometryUtils.DifferenceBetweenAngles((double)polylineAnalysis.SegmentAngles[i], (double)polylineAnalysis.SegmentAngles[i + 1], 360.0);
                if (num6 > num5)
                {
                    num5 = num6;
                }
                if (i > currentSegment)
                {
                    num4 += polylineAnalysis.SegmentLengths[i] * polylineAnalysis.SegmentAngles[i];
                }
            }
            labelPositionEvaluation.AverageAngle = (float)GeometryUtils.NormalizeAngle((double)((lengthAround != null) ? (num4 / (lengthAround.Value * 2f) + 225f) : (num4 / polylineLength + 225f)), 360.0);
            labelPositionEvaluation.MaxCornerAngle = num5;
            float angleForPosition = (float)GeometryUtils.NormalizeAngle((double)(polylineAnalysis.GetAngleForPosition(labelPositionEvaluation.Position) + 225f), 360.0);
            labelPositionEvaluation.ForwardDirection = (angleForPosition < 90f || angleForPosition > 270f);
            return labelPositionEvaluation;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can generate bitmap using export-bitmap command in maperetive. Then you rotate the whole. Hope this help!